1 amen for 2 berachot?
If I say בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה', שׁוֹמֵר אֶת־עַמּוֹ יִשְׂרָאֵל לָעַד אָמֵן, does the אמן at the end count towards a response to a Beracha I heard at the same time? E.g. if the Chazzan says Kaddish, and that Amen times perfectly to be one of the Amens for it?

Well you would have to have kavana at the very least to have it count for the kaddish

ברוך ה׳ לעולם אמן ואמן

The Mishneh Berurah O.C 124 Seif Katan 25 says:

מי שנזדמן לו לענות אמן על ב' דברים עונה שני אמנים זה אחר זה ויכוין בכל אמן את הענין על מה הוא עונה וטפי עדיף לומר אמן ואמן:
"One who happens to answer Amen to two (different) things should recite two Amens, one after the other, and should intend with each 'Amen' the specific matter to which he is responding; and it is more preferable to say 'Amen VeAmen'."

Mishneh Berurah in O.C 61 Seif Katan 28 says:

ואם נזדמן לו לענות על ב' דברים אפשר דאמן אחד יעלה לכאן ולכאן ואם יאמר אמן ואמן עדיף טפי
"And if it happens that one needs to answer Amen for two (different) things, it is possible that one Amen can count for both. However, if he says 'Amen VeAmen, it is preferable."

So in Siman 61, it seems that he raises the possibility that one amen would be good for both brachot.
